# Glossary deleting empty spaces and concepts appearing in italics

Tags: spacing, glossaries, italic

Im working in my thesis. When I included the glossary and started using the `\gls{}` and `\Gls{}` commands, all the "concepts" in the definition appear without spaces and in italics. For instance, when I used the command `\Gls{Learning Rate}`, the result was the following:

*LearningRate*

The Latex document is using the default configuration of the glossary package, so this term should've appeared like:

**Learning Rate**

The glossary entry is defined as follows

```
\newglossaryentry{Learning Rate}
{
    name=Learning Rate,
    description={Parámetro que controla \say{la cantidad de cambio} que experimentan las constantes de la red neuronal en función de su error. Valores muy bajos pueden causar que el proceso de optimización se atore en valles de la función de costo, mientras que valores muy altos pueden llevar a la convergencia temprana del modelo empleando constantes sub-óptimas. Cuando se establece un \textit{Initial Learning Rate} se hace referencia a un valor inicial para el \textit{learning rate} que posteriormente será alterado durante el entrenamiento para auxiliar en el proceso de minimización del error \cite{brownlee_2020}} 
}
```

All 9 definitions in my glossary appear like this, but Im unable to pinpoint the exact error. The best guess that I have is that the culprit is a conflict in packages but there isn't any warnings pointing to this being true. Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I try to make such an example based on the information you provided so far, I get the expected output.

Comment: In the code in your question, you define a glossary entry with the key `Learning Rate` but try to use it with the key `learning rate`. Is that just a typo in your question or the exact same code you used in your real document?

Comment: It is a typo. The key used is `Learning Rate` and the command is `\Gls{Learning Rate}`

Comment: With a code such as the following `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Learning Rate}
{
    name=Learning Rate,
    description={Parámetro que controla ...} 
}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\Gls{Learning Rate}
\printglossaries
\end{document}` I get the expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJTP7.png Could you therefore prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get?